# Marmalade and AppEasy

Tags: c++, marmalade

I wanted to know some general throughts about Marmalade and AppEasy. http://www.appeasymobile.com/

I've been following DrMop's tutorials on creating a game engine in Marmalade but noticed that  since the tutorials he's gone on to make AppEasy(with others). I have looked at it and have a couple of immediate concerns

1) How easily I can incorporate text files/xml files with XOML.

2) What degree of control I would have over the code base.

3) How deep the engine is and whether it has any comparitable rivels which are better.

I've started the project I'm working on with the IWGame engine that DrMop was using in his tutorials but was wondering that if all my fears are unfounded if it is worth carrying on?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried Marmalade Quick? It's out in public beta, allows coding in lua and is preloaded with box2D and Cocos2Dx

Comment: I've since moved away from Marmalade. I should close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Support for IwGame is coming to a close. IwGame is being replaced by the AppEasy Core SDK, which is an open source portable engine where Marmalade is just one of the platforms that it plans to support. AppEasy Core will also be open source so others can contribute to its development, submit bug fixes etc..

XOML + Lua or XOML + C++ or all 3 used together provide a very powerful easy to use environment. You can easily integrate text files, XML files, image files, sound files etc. You should check out the official web site appeasymobile, theres plenty of documentation and a drag and drop app builder that spits out cross platform apps based on XOML + Lua.

Cocos2d-x is a good alternative, but you will need to set up each dev environment for each platform you plan to support (massive pain to do) as it doesn't cross platform compile stuff for you. Although Marmalade do now have a stable interface to Cocos2dx which enables you to use Cocos2dx cross multiple platforms.

Comment: mat, I have looked through some of the examples, are there any examples you can specifically refer me too that deal with outside files as I can't see any? I had some trouble on a few of the examples, kept getting crashes when booting them up, something to do with the iterators, well that's where VS2010 stopped anyhow?

Comment: Or something that deals with multiple levels?

Comment: The Files example is an example that shows how to load text files into variables and then display the data. Many of the UI examples show how to load XML into an XML variables then bind the data to lists and data grids (XMLVariables is a good example). You can also load files from local or remote storage, so your files can be located on a web server. You also have access to the standard Lua libraries which can handle file loading / saving. If you go the C++ route then you get access to all of that functionality as well as the CzFile API which can be used to handle files in C++.

Comment: I'm fining it very difficult to see the examples when every project I seem to make breaks. Unhandled exception at 0x08222bc6 (Hello World.s86) in s3e_simulator_debug.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffff. I'm trying to make it through the Appeasy for Marmalade tool but pretty much every project has the same error in the _IwGxMetric class in the Increment function.

Comment: @Mat when do you plan to open AppEasy core to open source? as IwGame is no longer supported it would be best for us, its users, to move with it to AppEasy...

Comment: We are still in the process of documenting and tidying the SDK, its grown substantially and continues to grow weekly so its taking a while. We will post more info to drmop in the near future, including an alpha version.